# jQuery UI datepicker enable dates for visible month via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jQuery UI datepicker running on website where only certain dates are enabled based on the previous drop down selections (I use a MySQL query to get dates for entire year). Once the date is received it is passed to the datepicker and only those dates are enabled. I have achieved the desired behavior but the issue is that when I fetch dates for entire year, the MySQL query takes a long time to get the dates.

What I want to achieve now is to query first 3 months dates and enable them on datepicker, once the user navigates to 3rd month query next 3 months and set the dates in datepicker. By this I wont put pressure on database and also the calendar loads faster.

Is this possible?

The codes are very lengthy, I am posting the portion that enables/disables the dates:

```
var datepickerDateFilter = function (date) {
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = date.getDate();
    var date_string = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
    if ($courseDates.length > 0 && $.inArray(date_string, $courseDates) != -1) {
        return [true];
    }
    return [false];
};
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    beforeShowDay: datepickerDateFilter
});
//code goes here
```

Comment: never seen jQuery UI calendar. Post link to docs. Do you mean datepicker?

Comment: Did you try nd use beforeShowDay ( http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay )  to get the proper months/days? It should also trigger when browsing to another month. What I mean is; maybe you can keep track of the months you have loaded, and load new months as required.

Comment: I have used beforeShowDay. Will update some codes.

Comment: charlietfl: sorry abt that. I was talking about datepicker :)

Comment: Is there any way you can retrieve the dates via ajax? So you can fetch them from within beforeShowDay if they're not loaded yet for a specific month.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Optimize your queries before doing anything else. As for jQuery UI datepicker:

- Declare a variable that holds the available dates, grouped by year and month. This will make the lookup faster plus it allows you to differentiate between these two cases:

  - dates for XXXX-YY have not been fetched
  - dates for XXXX-YY have been fetched but there are no dates for this period
- Probe that variable on [**`onChangeMonthYear`**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear) event; if dates for specified YYYY-MM are not set, fire an ajax request to update the array.
- When the ajax request completes, update the array and trigger the [**`refresh`**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-refresh) method

Partial example:

```javascript
var availableDates = {};
// once populated, the availableDates variable should look like:
// {
//     2013: {
//         11: {
//             20: true,
//             21: true,
//             29: true
//         }
//         12: {
//             20: true,
//             21: true,
//             29: true
//         }
//     },
//     2014: {
//         1: {
//             1: true,
//             2: true,
//             9: true
//         }
//     }
// }
function populateAvailableDates(y, m, input) {
    $.ajax("/fetch-dates", {year: y, month: m}, function (data) {
        for ( /* each d in data */ ) {
            availableDates[y][m][d] = true;
        }
        $(input).datepicker("refresh");
    });
}    
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var d = date.getDate();
        return [availableDates[y] && availableDates[y][m] && availableDates[y][m][d] ? true : false, ""];
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function (y, m) {
        if (!availableDates[y]) {
            availableDates[y] = {};
        }
        if (!availableDates[y][m]) {
            availableDates[y][m] = {};
            populateAvailableDates(y, m, this);
        }
    }
});
// populate the array with datepicker's defaultDate
populateAvailableDates(2013, 11, $("#datepicker")[0]);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It worked with some adjustment to work with my codes.

Comment: what do you mean bu /* each d in data */

Comment: @behz4d the question does not contain example AJAX data. The coder must replace `each d in data` with appropriate code.